# Titanium Android module for pdf

Tags: android, pdf, titanium-mobile

Has anyone found a way to open or view a PDF file on Android? 
Is there any module in Titanium to open a PDF file within an Android app.

Answer (score 0):

Either you use and Intent to open it in the end-users pdf reader but if you need to open it in your app you can use this library:
https://marketplace.appcelerator.com/apps/6897?restoreSearch=true#!overview

Intent:

```
    try {
var f = Ti.Filesystem.getFile('your.pdf');
Ti.Android.currentActivity.startActivity(Ti.Android.createIntent({
    action: Ti.Android.ACTION_VIEW,
    type: 'application/pdf',
    data: f.getNativePath()
}));
}
    catch (err) {
var alertDialog = Titanium.UI.createAlertDialog({
    title: 'No PDF Viewer',
    message: 'We tried to open a PDF but failed. Do you want to search the marketplace for a PDF viewer?',
    buttonNames: ['Yes','No'],
    cancel: 1
});
alertDialog.show();
alertDialog.addEventListener('click', function(evt) {
    if (evt.index == 0) {
        Ti.Platform.openURL('http://search?q=pdf');
    }
});
```

}

Comment: I need to open it in my own app.. Is there any free module I can use ?

Comment: Is mupdf can be integrated with titanium ?

Comment: Never mind, that was for iOS, I found that you can use google docs viewer for easy implementation. webview that loads: http://docs.google.com/viewer?url=addresstoyourpdf.pdf

Comment: Sorry, we were unable to find the document at the original source. Verify that the document still exists.

Comment: that was just an example addresstoyourpdf.pdf does not actually exist... https://docs.google.com/viewer?url=http://www.georges-rech.fr/media/Retours/retour.fr.pdf

Comment: ah I see.. Is there any free module to use when I need to open pdf in my own app ?